# Kafka on multiple instances of ec2

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka, trying to do a project. Wanted to do it as it would be in real life example, but I am kinda confused. While searching thru the internet I found that if I want to have 3 brokers and 3 zookeepers, to provide replication factor = 2 and quorum, I need 6 EC2 instances. I am looking thru youtube to find some examples, but as far as I see all of them show multiple brokers on one cluster. From my understanding it's better to keep ZKs and all brokers separately on each VM, so if one goes down I still have all of the rest. Can you confirm that ?

Also, wondering how to set partitioning. Is it important at the beginning of creating a topic, or I change that later when I need to scale ?

Thanks in advance

looking for information on yt, google.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use [MSK Serverless](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/serverless.html) and forget how many machines exist.

Kafka 3.3.1 doesn't need Zookeeper anymore. Zookeeper doesn't need to be separate machines (although recommended). You can also run multiple brokers on one server... So, I'm not fully sure why you would need 6 for replication factor of 2.

Regarding partitions, yes, create it ahead of time (over provision, if necessary) since you cannot easily move data across partitions when you do scale

Comment: Yes but in case one machine goes down the other would keep working. That's the reason

Comment: Still, you can use 2 servers for that, rather than 6. Like I said, use MSK. That's all handled for you.

Comment: I wish but the account im using for the project is limited so I can't use MSK. But the minimum servers I would say is 3. On each I have kafka + ZK, which provides me quorum i case of a server's failure.

Comment: If you lose a Zookeeper on one of those servers, no, you don't have quorum. Therefore, you want 5, minimum. 3 running Zookeeper+Kafka, then two more with only Zookeeper (or some combination like that, if you want more brokers). I suggest [using Ansible](https://docs.confluent.io/ansible/current/overview.html) to manage this